# How to set the UITableView Section title programmatically (iPhone/iPad)?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ipad, storyboard, iboutlet

I've created a `UITableView` in Interface Builder using `storyboards`. The `UITableView` is setup with `static cells` and a number of different sections.

The issue I'm having is that I'm trying to setup my app in several different languages. To do this I need to be able to change the `UITableView` section titles somehow.

Please can someone help me out? Ideally I'd like to approach the issue using `IBOutlets` however I suspect this isn't even possible in this case. Any advice and suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: Note to future readers: ['Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541). Make sure to ask clear, focused questions.

Answer (score 291, accepted):

Once you have connected your UITableView `delegate` and `datasource` to your controller, you could do something like this:

#### ObjC

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSString *sectionName;
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            sectionName = NSLocalizedString(@"mySectionName", @"mySectionName");
            break;
        case 1:
            sectionName = NSLocalizedString(@"myOtherSectionName", @"myOtherSectionName");
            break;
        // ...
        default:
            sectionName = @"";
            break;
    }    
    return sectionName;
}
```

---

#### Swift

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    let sectionName: String
    switch section {
        case 0:
            sectionName = NSLocalizedString("mySectionName", comment: "mySectionName")
        case 1:
            sectionName = NSLocalizedString("myOtherSectionName", comment: "myOtherSectionName")
        // ...
        default:
            sectionName = ""
    }
    return sectionName
}
```

Comment: You sure that actually gets called if you setup the story board using static cells? I doesn't seem like it's being invoked.

Comment: Ah it seems like you have to implement `numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView:` to get it called.

Comment: For static cells, (most) all the other data source methods are not implemented.

Comment: @drewish `numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView:` implemented in IB for static cells.

Comment: drewish is right - if you implement `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` , then the title method is called and overries the storyboard. Since this is a static tableview then it's pretty ok to override it with a method that returns a constant number @wcochran

Comment: But how do you dynamically change the header? How do you invoke this method?

Comment: Just call the the reloadData() function from your UITableView instance. That way all data for your UITableView will be refreshed, this includes the invoke of the function from above.

Answer (score 18):

If you are writing code in Swift it would look as an example like this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?
{
    switch section
    {
        case 0:
            return "Apple Devices"
        case 1:
            return "Samsung Devices"
        default:
            return "Other Devices"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Use the UITableViewDataSource method

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Answer (score 6):

**titleForHeaderInSection** is a *delegate method of UITableView* so to apply header text of section write as follows,

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return @"Hello World";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that `-(NSString *)tableView:
titleForHeaderInSection:` is not called by UITableView if `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` is implemented in delegate of UITableView;

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about past versions of `UITableView` protocols, but as of iOS 9, `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?` is part of the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol.

```
   class ViewController: UIViewController {

      @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

      override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         tableView.dataSource = self
      }
   }

   extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
      func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
         return "Section name"
      }
   }
```

You don't need to declare the `delegate` to fill your table with data.

Comment: `extension` appears to not be needed with Swift 5.3. Xcode build messate: "'SettingsViewController' inherits conformance to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource' from superclass here"

Answer (score 2):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return 45.0f; 
//set height according to row or section , whatever you want to do!
}
```

section label text are set.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *sectionHeaderView;

        sectionHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:
                             CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 120.0)];


    sectionHeaderView.backgroundColor = kColor(61, 201, 247);

    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:
                            CGRectMake(sectionHeaderView.frame.origin.x,sectionHeaderView.frame.origin.y - 44, sectionHeaderView.frame.size.width, sectionHeaderView.frame.size.height)];

    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [headerLabel setTextColor:kColor(255, 255, 255)];
    headerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [headerLabel setFont:kFont(20)];
    [sectionHeaderView addSubview:headerLabel];

    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            headerLabel.text = @"Section 1";
            return sectionHeaderView;
            break;
        case 1:
            headerLabel.text = @"Section 2";
            return sectionHeaderView;
            break;
        case 2:
            headerLabel.text = @"Section 3";
            return sectionHeaderView;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return sectionHeaderView;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Nothing wrong with the other answers but this one offers a
>   non-programmatic solution that may be useful in situations where one
>   has a small static table. The benefit is that one can organize the
>   localizations using the storyboard. One may continue to export
>   localizations from Xcode via XLIFF files. Xcode 9 also has several [new tools to make localizations](https://www.ibabbleon.com/copywriter-translator/2017/06/whats-new-in-localization-in-xcode-9-ios-11/) easier.

(original)

I had a similar requirement. I had a static table with static cells in my Main.storyboard(Base). To localize section titles using .string files e.g. Main.strings(German) just select the section in storyboard and note the Object ID

[image: Object ID]

Afterwards go to your string file, in my case Main.strings(German) and insert the translation like:

```
"MLo-jM-tSN.headerTitle" = "Localized section title";
```

### Additional Resources:

- [Apple WWDC 2017](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/401/)
- [Medium Article on Localization ~ Xcode 9 /
  Swift 4](https://medium.com/@ezeokeonyekachi_84156/localization-of-ios-app-in-swift-4-and-xcode-9-3c7c7d53ae11)

Answer (score 0):

[image][![enter image description here][2]][2]tableView with custom Designed Section Design

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let width = width(text: myArr[section].date, height: 30)
    let headerLabel:UILabel = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width / 2 - ((width + 30) / 2), y: 0, width: width + 30, height: 30))
    headerLabel.text = myArr[section].date
    headerLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.AppRed
    headerLabel.textAlignment = .center
    headerLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
    headerLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    let headerView:UIView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0 , y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 40))
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    headerView.addSubview(headerLabel)
    headerView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    return headerView
    
}
func width(text: String, height: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
    ]
    let attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes)
    let constraintBox = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height)
    let textWidth = attributedText.boundingRect(with: constraintBox, options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading], context: nil).width.rounded(.up)
    
    return textWidth
}
```

Table Section Designed custom

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9VIv.jpg