# Set section's title after connection process

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsurlconnection

I have a UITableView that displays data from invoking a REST web service.
I'd like in that UITableView to set section's title from an NSMutableArray that get its data after connection to the Web Service.
Can I control the process as follows:

- Connecting to the web service and populate all NSMutableArray
- Get data from a specific NSMutableArray
- Set section's title and then show the UITableView.

The problem is that the compiler triggers the UITableView before getting data from web service.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this for setting the section headers, using this method should allow the next method call to work as intended
[Set UITableView Section Header Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505708/how-to-set-the-uitableview-section-title-programmatically-iphone-ipad)

**Call this after the Data has been loaded from your REST service.**

*the reloadData method reloads both rows and sections, so should correctly load not only your new section headers but any new data for the rows*

```
[myTableView reloadData]
```

*(i.e. in ViewDidLoad If you're loading the data in ViewWillLoad. Or if you know that the code following your data loading only is called after the array is filled)*

Using this approach, you should be able to not only