# UITableView with set number of sections, variable number of row per section

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I would like to implement a tableview with the number of sections that is known before run time but the number of rows per section are determined during run time.  Something like this where there will always be 26 sections (1 for each letter) but the number of places under each letter would change.
[image: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/dcba4426063e4d2b8a48c27ceb8831f3582f3647/687474703a2f2f73332e6d656469612e73717561726573706163652e636f6d2f70726f64756374696f6e2f313336383332312f31363130363738322f5f554c4954732d6e4456376b2f5450526739505f4e7448492f41414141414141414569382f67465761695444335967772f73313630302f4170706c6525324244656661756c7425324253656374696f6e2532425469746c6525324256696577732e706e67]

Would I use static cells or dynamic prototypes and can someone give me some pointers on how to implement this?

Comment: Post the code you have up until now.

Comment: Just use a standard tableview with dynamic prototypes where `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` returns a static integer. and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` returns the correct number of rows for each section.

Comment: @RoboticCat thanks I will try that, will the section headers still appear if I use dynamic prototypes?

Comment: Use the `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` method and return a String specific to each section if you want to have section headers. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10505708/558933

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a standard tableview with dynamic prototypes and implement the following methods where:

- `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` returns a static integer
- `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` returns the correct number of rows for each section
- `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` returns a String specific to each section header (example: [How to set the UITableView Section title programmatically (iPhone/iPad)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10505708/558933))

Comment: I think you accidentally put the same method signature for each. Line 1 should be `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this: [Addressbook UI Sample](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/)

Though this is in Objective C but its easy to know what functions you need to call from swift code as both swift and Objective C tableview delegates are almost same.