# Static cell at the bottom of a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a table view filled with contacts. At the very bottom of the table view (after the last contact) I would like to have a static table view cell that is always there with custom content.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Create a custom `UIView` and make it as a `tableFooterView`. That's it

Comment: Ok. So you are saying that I should put a UIView with a button in it and make that go to the bottom with that tableFooterView? How do I set the contraint that way?

Comment: Exactly! It's simple and works well. But you'll need to implement some `UITableViewDelegate` methods

Comment: I am sorry that this is a stupid question, but how do I add the constraint to be the bottom of all the table view cells?

Comment: Sorry! What did you mean by saying *all of the table view cells?*

Comment: I mean at the bottom of the table view, so after the last cell

Comment: Ok! I'll show you. How it's done.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: never mind, I was able to figure it out by this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38178509/swift-add-footer-view-in-uitableview. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome! As I promised I have posted an answer below. You shouldn't do anything. It's just recommendation and I hope it helps to others and beginners. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let button = UIButton.init()
    button.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 44)
    button.setTitle("✚", for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkGray, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handle(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    self.tableView.tableFooterView = button
}
```

And associated function:

```
func handle(sender: UIButton) {
    print("Tapped")
}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Another way! We can implement by using `UITableViewDelegate`. And here's the example below, how we done.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let button = UIButton.init()
        button.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 44)
        button.setTitle("✚", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkGray, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handle(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        return button
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 44
    }


    func handle(sender: UIButton) {
        print("Tapped")
    }
```

Note: Second option is always visible on the main screen like a section header.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that the array you are using to populate your `UITableView`is called 'contactsArray'.

What you would need to do in the following delegate method is add an additional row e.g:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return contactsArray+1

}
```

Then you would need to handle this logic e.g:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

if indexPath.row >= contactsArray.count{
        print("Last Row")
    }
}
```