# how to bring button inFront of tableviewController in swift 4?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, swift4

I have a table view controller and the only way for me is to using that so please don't tell me use viewController instead of tableviewController here is my codes for adding a button and this Button is shown in the last cell But I want when user scrolling table view the button be at the bottom of screen without moving

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let submitButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: view.frame.origin.y + view.frame.size.height, width: self.view.frame.width - 10 , height: 50))

    submitButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 180/255, green: 40/255, blue: 56/255, alpha: 1.0)
    submitButton.setTitle("Submit", for: .normal)
    submitButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 15)
    submitButton.titleLabel?.textColor = .white
    submitButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(submit), for: .touchUpInside)
    submitButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    view.addSubview(submitButton)
```

Comment: Adding button as footer of the tableview section can be a workaround. Refer this link if you are trying : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38178509/swift-add-footer-view-in-uitableview

Comment: this will not work in tableview controller I want  the button be I the bottom of screen in any situation but in this link when I run the app I need to scroll table view to see the button

Comment: Then there can be one approach of adding button on `self.view.window`. But in this approach you have to remove the button when view will disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach if it suits your scenario:

```
var submitButton = UIButton()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    submitButton.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: view.frame.origin.y + view.frame.size.height, width: self.view.frame.width - 10 , height: 50)

    submitButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 180/255, green: 40/255, blue: 56/255, alpha: 1.0)
    submitButton.setTitle("Submit", for: .normal)
    submitButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 15)
    submitButton.titleLabel?.textColor = .white
    submitButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(submit), for: .touchUpInside)
    submitButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    self.view.window?.addSubview(submitButton)
}
```

But in this scenario you have to remove the button from superview in `viewWillDisappear` :

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self. submitButton.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

declare button as a variable

```
   var submitButton:UIButton!
```

and in viewDidLoad

```
    submitButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 50 , width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 10 , height: 50))        
    submitButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 180/255, green: 40/255, blue: 56/255, alpha: 1.0)
    submitButton.setTitle("Submit", for: .normal)
    submitButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 15)
    submitButton.titleLabel?.textColor = .white
    submitButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(submit), for: .touchUpInside)
    submitButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5        
    self.view.addSubview(submitButton)
```

and implement this method

```
 override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

  submitButton.frame = CGRect.init(x: submitButton.frame.origin.x, y:  UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height + scrollView.contentOffset.y - 50 , width: submitButton.frame.width, height: submitButton.frame.height)

}
```

Comment: again I got the same result

Comment: add that line after addSubview

Comment: again still there is a problem

Comment: not showning or what

Comment: no the button is still in the bottom of table view not bottom of the screen ( the user should scroll tableview to see the button) But I want the button be I the bottom of screen in any situation

Comment: try update .......

Comment: I used the code and for subview used self.view.addSubview(submitButton) But again still problem doesn't solved :(

Comment: see final edit otherWise i will create constraints for you

Comment: I run these codes and got this error 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors  and for the  let submitButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: I got the same result( the button will show if you scroll to the down)

Comment: see update .....

Comment: this footer will be in the bottom of section and until reach the last cell in the section it doesn't show

Comment: you have 1 section ???

Comment: I solved it for you

Comment: this is worked for me      self.navigationController.view But thanks for helping

Comment: you may try this also i tested it and it worked perfectly

Comment: The problem is that view is scroll able any content added to it scrolls so we handle this in DidEndScroll delegate method as TableViewController inherits from UIScrollview

Comment: so now after back to the last page still  can see the button how can I hide that when the tableViewController is been dismissed ?

Comment: you use my solution or navigation.view

Comment: I used navigation and that problem was solved too I used viewWillDisappear for hide button now every things working well