# Add multiple footers to UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to have two footers in my `UITableView`. I have used this to add a footer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38178757/10466651

I tried adding two footers like this in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
button.setTitle("Submit", for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
customView.addSubview(button)
tableView.tableFooterView = customView

let customView2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
customView2.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
let button2 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
button2.setTitle("Submit", for: .normal)
button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction2), for: .touchUpInside)
customView2.addSubview(button2)
tableView.tableFooterView = customView2
```

But it just goes over eachother. I tried playing with the `CGRect y`, but still wont work for me.

Comment: Basically, you want put two buttons into footerview?

Comment: I was thinking about two buttons as footer(or 2 footers if possible?)

Comment: You can draw a `containerView` first, set it as the `footerView`, then put the two buttons inside

Comment: tableView.tableFooterView = customView
tableView.tableFooterView = customView2
here the "=" is assignment operator. and you are first assigning customView1 and then assigning customView2. it will not add two tablefooters that way for sure. You will need to create a single footer view (because tableview can take only one) and add your buttons or any other views in that container view and assign it to the tableview

Answer (score 1):

This

```
tableView.tableFooterView = customView2
```

with override the first

```
tableView.tableFooterView = customView
```

You need to make 1 view that contains both ( `customView` + `customView2` ) , then assign it as the footer

---

```
let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 115))
customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
button.setTitle("Submit 1", for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
customView.addSubview(button)  
let button2 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 65, width: 100, height: 50))
button2.setTitle("Submit 2", for: .normal)
button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction2), for: .touchUpInside)
customView.addSubview(button2)
tableView.tableFooterView = customView
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I add a small spacing between the buttons?